# change Linespread in longtable and table

Tags: tables, longtable, line-spacing

In my document i am using a `\linespread{1.5}` for the whole document, but I would like to have a `\linespread{1}` for tables and long tables. How can I change it?

Comment: put `\renewcommand\linespread{1}` before the table (You might want to look at the `setspace` package which takes care of some issues with line spacing. (Of course don't do this at all unless absolutely forced by submission rules, it hardly ever improves the look of the document)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hey again. If I renew the commadn before the table ill need to renew it again after the table, right? As my table is pretty tight the huge line spacing makes it to look wrong. Thats why I want lesser linespacing there :D

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cant seem to use you tip even in a minimal example

Comment: either reset afterwards or in a local group. I didn't mean single-spacing the table looks bad, I meant applying linespread to the rest of the document looks bad (but sometimes it is required)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle With that line before the table (or before anything) nothing changes in my doc.

Comment: @AnderBiguri sorry typo in first comment, should be `\baselinestretch`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great asnwer! A bit late (this was my master thesis, I am already in my PhD!), but great for the community! Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: sorry.......:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following shows different values of `\baselinestretch` applying to text and longtables within the same page:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\def\a{One two three four five six. }
\def\b{\a\a\par Red green blue. \a\a\a\par Yellow black \a\a\a\a}

\begin{document}

111! \b

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2.5}\selectfont

222! \b

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
aaa aa aa aaa a a a&1&bbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&1&bbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaa&1234567890&bbbbb b b b b bbbbbbbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\b

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\selectfont

111!

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
aaa aa aa aaa a a a&1&bbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&1&bbbb\\
aaaaaaaaaaa&1234567890&bbbbb b b b b bbbbbbbbbbb\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2.5}\selectfont

222!

\b\b\b

\end{document}
```